# Monit STUN / TURN server

Tags: debian, monit

I set up a STUN & TURN server (with TLS support) using [reTurnServer](http://resiprocate.org/), on a Debian 8 VPS, using the official Debian package `resiprocate-turn-server`.

I am already using [Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) to monitor different services, disk usage and some specific files;
I was wondering how to monitor my STUN / TURN server.

For now, I am just checking the hosts, CPU and RAM usage with the following config:

```
check process turn-server with pidfile /var/run/reTurnServer/reTurnServer.pid
  start program = "/bin/systemctl start resiprocate-turn-server.service"
  stop program  = "/bin/systemctl stop resiprocate-turn-server.service"
  if failed host stun.my-domain.com port 3478 type udp for 3 cycles then alert
  if failed host turn.my-domain.com port 3478 type udp for 3 cycles then alert
  if failed host turn.my-domain.com port 5349 type tcp for 3 cycles then alert
  if cpu > 75% for 3 cycles then alert
  if total cpu > 80% for 5 cycles then alert
  if mem > 512 MB for 5 cycles then alert
```

But -- **unless I am really not getting the point of such protocols, which is definitely possible** --, those checks are made over the classical HTTP protocol.
I would prefer to actually use the `stun` and `turn/turns` protocols to check if my server is still up.

STUN :

```
stun:stun.my-domain.com:3478
```

TURN :

```
turns:turn.my-domain.com:5349
```

TURN also might require credentials (`username` for the ID, and `credential` as the password).

Does anyone know how to do this? Is it even possible?